# how to write results of a formula directly into an excel range by VBA code

Tags: excel, formula, listobject, vba

I have a series of functions for each of listobject columns. The file is heavy and crashing, so I want just to keep the results of each formula as static values. I can allocate formula to the range and ask excel to convert the range to value. But I am wondering if there is a way to ask VBA to write only the static values in the range instead of the formula itself. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub calculate2()
Dim i As Long, t As Long
t = Timer
    With Sheet3.ListObjects(1)
      For i = 3 To 9
         .ListColumns(i).DataBodyRange.ClearContents
         .Range.Cells(2, i).Formula = sheets3.range("formula").cells(i,1).formula
         .ListColumns(i).DataBodyRange = .ListColumns(i).DataBodyRange.Value
      Next i
    End With
Debug.Print Timer - t
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `.Range.Cells(2, i).Value = .ListColumns(i).Total`?

Comment: Hey, Actually I am just using the total row for keeping my formulas. something like this is stored there.

`=IFERROR(IF(COUNTIFS('ZZ84'!$B:$B,[@WO],'ZZ84'!$E:$E,"=*V99",'ZZ84'!$L:$L,"<>")=1,1,IF(SUMIFS('ZZ84'!$G:$G,'ZZ84'!$B:$B,[@WO],'ZZ84'!$L:$L,"")/((SUMIFS('ZZ84'!$G:$G,'ZZ84'!$B:$B,[@WO]))/10)/10=1,0,1-SUMIFS('ZZ84'!$G:$G,'ZZ84'!$B:$B,[@WO],'ZZ84'!$L:$L,"")/((SUMIFS('ZZ84'!$G:$G,'ZZ84'!$B:$B,[@WO]))/10)/10-0.01)),"")` I changed the code. The formula is a text string which starts with =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an answer to my own question, 
What I was looking for is: " application.Evaluate " I am posting that so if anyone came here by search can find the idea and the sollution I eventually found. Here is an example:

```
Sheet3.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange = [IFERROR(IF(COUNTIFS(ZZ84!$B:$B,[WO],ZZ84!$E:$E,"=*V99"‌​,ZZ84!$L:$L,"<>")=1,1,0),"")]
```

in this case there is no need to loop and for each range has to write needful line of code (Embed the function in VBA, what I excatly was looking for). The only different in above function with directly putting that in a excel cell is using [WO] instead of [@WO]. So evaluat caculate an array of data and directly write that in specified range. (here body range of list columns 3 ).

For me it helped to avoid crashes beacause of voilate calculation by my functions.

Another simple example would be:

```
range("b1:b10")=[if(row(1:10),if(a1:a10>3,"big","Small"))]
```

or

```
range("b1:b10") = evaluate("if(row(1:10),if(" & range("a1:a10").address&">3,""big"",""small""))")
```

Kind regards,
M