# Excel Create a IF statement that produces a value of 1 in Excel column

Tags: java, python, excel, vba

I am attempting to code a script that runs in excel. I currently have an excel file with over 1,000+ State initials in one column, for example, NJ, MI, OH, TX. With that being said, I have 3 other columns that represent regions A, B, and C.

[image: Image of Excel Document]

If the state initial is NJ, I'm trying to return the value 1 in the specific corresponding region column. For instance, if the state initial is NJ return 1 in the corresponding column and row (Region B). If the state initial is TX return 1 in the corresponding column and row (Region A). And if the state initial is Ontario return the value 1 in (Region C), and so on.

Does anyone have any idea how I can complete this task? Using VBA, python, whichever language​ that will get it done the best.

Also please see attached picture for a better understanding. The code below is my attempt to do one state at a time.

```vb
Sub Region()
    If Range("A:A").Value = "NJ" Then
        Range("C:C").Value = 1
    End If   
End Sub
```

Comment: How is a state assigned to a region?

Comment: I chose to assign those states to region A, B or C. NJ & OH are in region B, MI & TX in region A and Ontario in region C.  Also each state can only be assigned to one region.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one at a time would work but if the data is large you might consider version 2 below...

So, try this:

```
=IF(A1="NJ",1,0)
```

entered in cell C1, then just drag down.

You might consider a table of values and deal with all states in one function :

```
=vlookup(A1,$G$1:$H$4,2,0)
```

An image of version 2:
[image]

You can also use index() with match() :

```
=index($H$1:$H$4,match(A1,$G$1:$G$4,0))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Because I am dealing with over 10k + states / data what do you recommend for having a script that could consist of all the states and input a 1 in its respected fields? For instance, If "AL, AK, AR, CO, HI" return value 1 for  region A / column E, If "CT, DE, FL, GA" return value 1 for region B / column F and If "Alberta, Ontario, Quebec" return value 1 for region C / column G?

Comment: So 1000 or 10000? You can apply the same logic with a script or even use the formula and paste special values once it has calculated which will keep the overhead down...

Comment: Do a search on here, there may be similar problems already discussed, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48217693/4961700

Answer (score -1):

If ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value = "Percentage" And ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow - 1, 5).Value <> "Select" Then
    MsgBox "Please reset the Percentage Type Option as Select for Cell Highlighted in Red Color " & Chr(13)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow - 1, 5).Interior.ColorIndex = 38
    Call ResetCustomDocProp
    Exit Function
ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value = "Percentage" And ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow - 1, 6).Value <> vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "Please set the Percentage Rate Cell should be Blank for Cell Highlighted in Red Color " & Chr(13)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow - 1, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 38
    Call ResetCustomDocProp
    Exit Function
ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value = "Percentage" And ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow - 1, 5).Value = "Select" And InStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow - 1, 6).NumberFormat, "%") <= 0 Then
    MsgBox "Please Set the Percentage Rate Cell should be format as % for Cell Highlighted in Red Color " & Chr(13)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow - 1, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 38
    Call ResetCustomDocProp
    Exit Function
ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value = "Percentage" And ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow - 1, 53).Value = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "Please set the Formulla for the Quoted Percentage Rate in Figure Cell Highlighted in Red Color " & Chr(13)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow - 1, 53).Interior.ColorIndex = 38
    Call ResetCustomDocProp
    Exit Function
ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value = "Percentage" And ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow - 2, 53).Value = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "Please set the Formulla for the Estimated Percentage Rate in Figure Cell Highlighted in Red Color " & Chr(13)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow - 2, 53).Interior.ColorIndex = 38
    Call ResetCustomDocProp
    Exit Function

Else
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow - 1, 4).Value <> vbNullString Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow - 1, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 20
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow - 1, 5).Interior.ColorIndex = 20
    ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow - 1, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 20
End If